# Read / Write from a file; combine matched line with line after it

Tags: perl

I'm reading from a log file that looks like this:

```
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 0] lib/util_sock.c:write_data(562)
    write_data: write failure in writing to client 158.136.148.93. Error Connection reset by peer
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 0] lib/util_sock.c:send_smb(769)
    Error writing 4 bytes to client. -1. (Connection reset by peer)
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 1] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(950)
    pubcen04 (158.136.156.79) connect to service sfengel initially as user sfengel (uid=18375, gid=122) (pid 5044)
```

If an entry contains make_connnection or close_cnum I'm writing that entry to another file called data.txt. So, when my program matches a line, it matches the line where make_connection is located, but I also need information from the line directly underneath it. My latest attempt to do this is by using the join function but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code Here:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;

my $logfile = 'log.smbd';
my $cnt;

open( my $info, '<', $logfile )
        or die "Could not open file '$logfile' $!";

while( my $line = <$info> ) {
        if( index( $line, 'make_connection' || 'close_cnum') != -1 ) {
                chomp($line);
                $line = join(" ",(<$info> =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+)/))."\n";
                $line =~ s/\[//g;
                $line =~ s/\]//g;
                my @array = split / /, $line;
                open( my $fh, '>>/etc/data.txt' );
                        print ($fh "\"$array[0]\"\,", "\"$array[1]\"\,",\"$array[5]\"\," );
        }
}
```

Comment: Set $/ to [ and then it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow?  Please read the [About] page soon.  What happens?  Why didn't you show what happens?  My best guess is that the second argument to `join` is probably a list context, and `<>` in list context reads the whole file.  Don't mess around like that; Perl has ways of biting you.  Read the extra line explicitly.

Comment: Index looks to be the culprit here. That || doesn't look like it will do what you think.

Comment: Yes... new to the site. I should also mention this is my first day with perl

Answer (score -1):

You're doing this a much harder way you need. First off:

```
if( index( $line, 'make_connection' || 'close_cnum') != -1 ) {
```

Isn't going to do what you think it might - that `||` is tighter binding than you think - and so you're not going to be testing 'close_cnum' at all.

```
A || B
```

always returns "A" if it's true, and "B" if it isn't. And 'make_connection' isn't an empty string or zero, so it's "true".

I'd suggest something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n[";

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    next unless m/(make_connection|close_cnum)/; 
    my ( $date, $time, $call, $error_text ) = m/^([\d\/]+) ([\d\:]+). \d+\] (\S+)\n\s*(.*)/m;
    print "Date = $date\n";
    print "time = $time\n";
    print "call = $call\n";
    print "Error = $error_text\n";
    print "Full record:\n";
    print;
    print "\n---\n";
}

__DATA__
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 0] lib/util_sock.c:write_data(562)
    write_data: write failure in writing to client 158.136.148.93. Error Connection reset by peer
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 0] lib/util_sock.c:send_smb(769)
    Error writing 4 bytes to client. -1. (Connection reset by peer)
[2007/09/06 10:49:30, 1] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(950)
    pubcen04 (158.136.156.79) connect to service sfengel initially as user sfengel (uid=18375, gid=122) (pid 5044)
```

- We iterate through `DATA` - which is a special filehandle, and you can use your `<$info>` instead. (This is for testing)
- But because we've set `$/` to `[` it splits the file into chunks, and works through them.
- Sets `$_` to the contents of the current chunk, and applies a pattern match against it to extract the text you want. (note - by default a pattern match applies to `$_` which is useful).

I'm afraid I couldn't tell what you were aiming to catch with `$array[5]`, so I've guessed. But you should be able to tell what's going on there.